# How to programatically detect a weak Internet signal strength (Internet, Wi-Fi,Cellular Data etc..) in Universal Windows Apps?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

How to programtically  detect a weak signal strength (Internet, Wi-Fi,Mobile Data etc..) in Universal Windows Apps ??

I am developing a Universal Windows app, in which i want to know how can i detect Weak signal Internet Strength whether it might be LAN , Wi-fi , Cellular Data, how can i detect if the connection/ Signal Strength is slow or very poor etc..

Is there any means in which i can know  this in Universal Windows Apps ?

Please let me know the various options available through which i can achieve this

please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (ConnectionProfile profile in NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles()) //Get all active profiles (LAN, bluetooth, wifi, Cellular data, etc..)
{
   NetworkConnectivityLevel level = profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel(); //Get connectivity level for profile
   /*NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess         
                              ConstrainedInternetAccess
                              LocalAccess
                              None*/
  Byte signal = profile.GetSignalBars(); //Returns the signal level
  bool isWifi = profile.IsWlanConnectionProfile;
  bool isCellularData = profile.IsWwanConnectionProfile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to programtically detect a weak signal strength (Internet, Wi-Fi,Mobile Data etc..) in Universal Windows Apps ??

As @Stefano Balzarotti posted, you can use [GetConnectionProfiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getconnectionprofiles) method of [NetworkInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207293) class to get connection profile lists.

> how can i detect if the connection/ Signal Strength is slow or very poor etc..

You can get the signal strength from the result of [ConnectionProfile.GetSignalBars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getsignalbars.aspx)  method.

The official sample [Network information sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Network-Information-Sample-63aaa201) has completed demo about the features you want, you can download for testing.

Comment: The link for the sample is broken. Did you refer to this sample? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-appsample-networkhelper/networkhelper-sample-library/